# Joomla 1.7 custom toolbar button usage

Tags: joomla, toolbar, backend, joomla1.6

I've added a custom button into my component's backend toolbar with this code:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('libri.details','details.png','details.png','TOOLBAR_DETAILS',true);
```

This button needs that the admin checks one of the entries listed in the table.
You can see a screenshot [here](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/8966/backvh.jpg) if you haven't understood what I'm talking about 
The button is the one called "Dettagli" (no image at the moment).

I'm having some problems:

- How do I append the checked entry's id to the address generated from the button?
- I've put a details() method into the controller, it calls an instance of the model and a method inside it. The model's method returns to the controller the result of a query. How do I say to the controller to pass that result to a view called libro?

Answer (score 0):

1. All information in the page will be sent through POST to the Joomla controller (in this case, `libri`).  In your controller, you can use `JRequest::getVar('varNameHere');` to retrieve it.
2. `$this->setRedirect($urlOfView, $someStatusMessage)`